# Can I request to join a closed clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If a clan is "closed" can you still "join them" in a kind of request way or is there no way of joining the clan until it is changed to "anyone can join" or "invite only"?

I haven't yet tried to join because I'm currently in a clan as co-leader, but it is going a bit down hill for them and feel a move is appropriate but I don't want to leave to have to re-join the group again because I cannot get in the other clan.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant, once the can is set to `Closed`, they wont receive any join requests (as in physically). Its not like `Invite only` where you can still send a request to join.